# Ubuntu PPA for collectd?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm looking for a semi-official PPA for recent versions of collectd (5.2+).

There appear to be [several possible matches](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=collectd), but I'm hoping to find the "right" one for production use which will keep reasonably current and not vaporize under my feet.

Could anyone share a good PPA for installing modern collectd on ubuntu precise 12.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to give https://launchpad.net/~collectd/+archive/ubuntu/collectd-5.5 a try. It is roughly the same as the nightly builds mentioned by @ustuehler, except using the release tarballs.

Answer (score 8):

I found myself in the same situation and couldn't find pointers to recent 5.5.x versions on collectd's home page, nor on their wiki. Then I found collectd.org's [repositories on GitHub](https://github.com/collectd). The [README.md](https://github.com/collectd/collectd-ci/blob/master/README.md) file for their CI repository contains instructions on how to use the packages on RHEL/CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu.

To get the latest build of the "collectd-5.5" branch on Ubuntu 14.04, first add the release key:

```
curl http://pkg.ci.collectd.org/pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then specify the package source in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/collectd-ci.list` as:

```
deb http://pkg.ci.collectd.org/deb/ trusty collectd-5.5
```

Now you can install or update the package as usual.